# How do I change the originating address in truffle?

Tags: key, testing, truffle

My `truffle-config.js` has

```
const { alice } = require('./scripts/sandbox/accounts');
module.exports = {
  contracts_directory: "./contracts/main",
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "http://localhost",
      port: 8732,
      network_id: "*",
      secretKey: alice.sk,
      type: "tezos"
    },
```

and my test has

```
const { networks } = require('./../truffle-config');
networks.development.secretKey = charlie.sk;
tx = await contract_instance.register(bob.pkh);
```

But this function call/transaction is still originating from alice and not from charlie. How do I fix that? I would like to be able to change the caller throughout the unit test if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a solution myself using what is provided by Truffle to do what you want, so here is what I do. I guess you must be using Taquito. In this case, you can use this function to change the signer whenever you need:

```
const signerFactory = async pk => {
  await Tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(pk) });
  return Tezos;
};
```

However, this means that you have to create your own `Tezos` singleton object and you cannot use Truffle syntax anymore to bypass Truffle default settings, for example:

```
let contractInstance;

before(async () => {
    Tezos.setProvider({
      rpc: `${truffleConfig.networks.development.host}:${truffleConfig.networks.development.port}`
    });
    await signerFactory(alice.sk);

    const contract = await Contract.deployed();
    /**
     * Display the current contract address for debugging purposes
     */
    console.log("Contract deployed at:", contract.address);

    contractInstance = await Tezos.wallet.at(contract.address);
  });
```

and calling an entrypoint of the contract would look like what you do in a dapp:

```
tx = await contractInstance.register(bob.pkh).send();
```